# How can I restore my Internet access? ONLY program which still access internet is variety (wallpaper app)

Tags: networking, internet

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 Server was working perfectly, until AirVPN (Eddie) crashed.  Now, can't access internet normally.  (Variety wallpaper app) still works -- unexplained.  But can't otherwise access Internet.  Intranet (LAN) works perfectly fine.  Have checked route and believe it is damaged...  Removed IPtables and resolvconf to try and get it working; no effect.  Have access through VNC & Putty from Windows, but can't update, or get functional internet.  Below is printouts of relevant files.

Ping only work internally (inside LAN); however WILL NOT ping WAN.  Tried both name & number 100% packet loss.

P.S. All started with AirVPN crash; now can't access AirVPN (won't login, as internet is being restricted, but NOT BY FIREWALL.  Disabled & Removed.).

I'm at a loss, don't know what else to check/change???

route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination   Gateway       Genmask        Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0       192.168.10.1  0.0.0.0        UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.10.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0  U     100    0        0 enp4s0
```

ifconfig -a:

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:e4:e6:96
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2172:c8b8:68b0:e8cf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16964718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:177959938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1775612207 (1.7 GB)  TX bytes:256255723804 (256.2 GB)
          Interrupt:18

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:80980 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80980 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:6332206 (6.3 MB)  TX bytes:6332206 (6.3 MB)
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo enp4s0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp4s0
# iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
# gateway 192.168.10.1
# address 192.168.10.10
# netmask 255.255.255.0
# dns-nameservers 96.90.175.167  208.67.222.222

#Multicast for UPNP/DLNA Server
up route add -net 239.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev enp4s0
```

NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

EDIT: 6/12

OK, variety (wallpaper app) DOESN'T access internet either---was pulling images from hard drive (previously saved), when intenet was working.

Comment: stupid to ask, but DNS servers are set properly?  The one app could maybe have something hard coded in it to allow it to work sans-DNS or in case DNS is being blocked, etc.  You also have two `auto enp4s0` satements - one stand alone and one with the `auto lo enp4s0`

Comment: As  far as I can tell; but not sure how to verify?

Comment: pinged Google.com on Windows and used IP to test DNS, got no response..  Will change in router & reboot...

Comment: OK, THANK you for pointing me at the right direction; it was DNS!!; reinstalled resolvconf and added DNS directly; then restarted NetworkManager service and it's GOOOD!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solved; DNS was screwed...reinstalled resolveconf and restarted Network Manager Service...All Good; thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys.

Long week.

Bill